# How to extend site filter in multisite setup

Tags: experience-profile, search-facet

We have a multisite setup (both SXA and non-SXA sites) with Sitecore 9.3.
Need is to provide a filter in the Experience Profile to search site-specific contacts (a site filter just like in the Experience Analytics).
The preferred way is to have a fourth filter along with Channel, Outcomes, and Goal.

Question: How to add a site search filter in experience profile search?

[image]

UPDATE:
Below is what I received from Sitecore support.

> Personally I checked it and it is not easy to extend here. You need to
> look into two places:
>  >
>
> 1. The js file: "\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ExperienceProfile\Search\Search.js".
>    This is the file to control the search logic on the dashboard
>     >
> 2. The presentation detail of item "/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Search" in core
>    database. Experience Profile is a speak application. The Sitecore
>    items setting with client side js code will control the layout and
>    logic together.

Anybody had luck making this happen?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @RichardSeal I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: An update. We reached out to Sitecore support to see the possibility of doing this and how. It seems at present Experience Profile is pretty much locked and not much customization possible.

Comment: @kiran did you manage to find a solution or a workaround for adding a site search filter?

Comment: @AME Unfortunately nothing in Sitecore experience profile but we ended up with a decision that we will be doing this kind of filtering in Power BI.